# Div height not support

Tags: html, css

Div height is not support in below code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.Footer{
background-color:red;
width:673px;
height:1px;
}
</style>

<title>Fist</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Footer"></div>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

But its work below code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.Footer{
background-color:red;
width:673px;
height:1px;
}
</style>

<title>Second</title>
</head>

<body>
                        <div class="Footer"></div>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

How to set div height in 1st coding

Comment: 2 closing head and 2 closing body... interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first piece of code you have:

```
div class="Footer"></div>
```

which should be:

```
<div class="Footer"></div>
```

You also do not have a doctype set for your first example. I would suggest adding something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: is it possible to do with out <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: if i use <!DOCTYPE > in my web page  the letters are coming like stretched  in internet explore 9

Comment: The bare minimum you should use is <!DOCTYPE html> which is the doctype declaration for HTML5 documents and is the bare minimum for IE to run in standards mode and should also be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2):

why are you using 2 body tags??????????????
add < befor div tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
div class="Footer"></div>
</body>
```

You can add ***<*** before div tag